# Independency of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be random variables from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It has been shown that mutual independency implies pairwise independency, and when $n = 3$, pairwise independency does not imply mutual independency.

My question is, does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that, for any random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, if any $2,3,\dots,n-1$ of them are mutually independent, then all $n$ of them are mutually independent?

Comment: Do you see any obstacles when extending the construction used for $n = 3$ to higher $n$'s?

Comment: @Ilya Yes. My example is that $X, Y$ be iid Bernoulli(0.5) random variables and $Z = X + Y - 2XY$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such $n$.  For all $n > 2$, we can find random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ such that any $n-1$ of them are independent, but all $n$ of them are not.

The easiest example would be to let $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = -1) = \frac 12$ and define $X_n := \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i$.  Then any proper subset of $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ is mutually independent, but the full collection $X_1,...,X_n$ is clearly not mutually independent.